# sed: replace start of a string based on characters at the end of the string?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to use `sed` to insert either a `foo` or a `bar` based on the number at the end of the line. If the line ends with `1`, I need the line to start with `foo`. If the line ends with `2`, I need the line to start with `bar`.

I've been playing around with these kinds of solutions, but I'm stuck:

```
sed -e 's/^/foo/;s/:1$/:1/' input.txt
sed -e 's/:1$/^foo/' input.txt
```

input

```
aaaaa:1
bbbbb:2
ccccc:1
```

desired output

```
fooaaaaa:1
barbbbbb:2
fooccccc:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [select lines by text matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses) and apply separate substitutions to them:

```
$ sed -e '/:1$/s/^/foo/' -e '/:2$/s/^/bar/' input
fooaaaaa:1
barbbbbb:2
fooccccc:1
```